# Better way to get multiple tokens from a string? (Python 2)

Tags: python, string, join, split

If I have a string:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!"

I will often use the split() function to tokenize the string.

```
testString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!"
testTokens = testString.split(" ")
```

This will give me a list:

```
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog!']
```

If I want to remove the first token and keep the REST of the tokens intact, I will do something like this to make it a one-liner:

```
newString = " ".join(testTokens.split(' ')[1:]) # "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!"
```

Or, if I want a certain range:

```
newString = " ".join(testTokens.split(' ')[2:4]) # "brown fox"
newString = " ".join(testTokens.split(' ')[:3]) # "The quick brown"
```

Of course, I may want to split on something other than a space:

```
testString = "So.long.and.thanks.for.all.the.fish!"
testTokens = testString.split('.')

newString = ".".join(testTokens.split('.')[3:]) # "thanks.for.all.the.fish!"
```

Is this the BEST way to accomplish this? Or is there a more efficient or more readable way?

Comment: this looks fine to me. what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't think you want `testTokens.split(' ')` in all of your examples after the first. `testTokens` is already `testString.split(" ")`, so you just want to use it as-is.

Comment: If you're splitting on space, why not use `testString.split()` instead? It will handle consecutive spaces as a single one (though I suppose you might want to keep consecutive spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can take an optional second argument, signifying the maximum number of splits that should be made:

```
>>> testString.split(' ', 1)[1]
'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!'
```

This is much better than `" ".join(testTokens.split(' ')[1:])`, whenever it can be applied.

Thank you @abarnert for pointing out that `.split(' ', 1)[1]` raises an exception if there are no spaces. See [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) if that poses an issue.

---

Furthermore, there is also an [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) method, so you can use:

```
>>> testString.rsplit(' ', 6)[0]
'The quick brown'
```

instead of `" ".join(testTokens.split(' ')[:3])`.

Comment: The only problem with `.split(' ', 1)[1]` is that it raises an exception if there are no spaces; you can use `.partition(' ')[-1]` if that's an issue.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, I added that to the answer

Comment: Nice addition with `rsplit`. I'm not sure that's the absolute best example for it, but I'm sure the OP can figure out what it does and where he'd use it from your explanation and the link.

Comment: This works great - didn't know about the second argument. It will work for most cases I'm using and saves me the `join()` operation!

Answer (score 1):

Your current method is perfectly fine.  You can gain a very slight performance boost by limiting the number of splits.  For example:

```
>>> ' '.join(testString.split(' ', 4)[2:4])
'brown fox'
>>> ' '.join(testString.split(' ', 3)[:3])
'The quick brown'
>>> ' '.join(testString.split(' ', 1)[1:])
'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!'
```

Note that for smaller strings the difference will be negligible, so you should probably stick with your simpler code.  Here is an example of the minimal timing difference:

```
In [2]: %timeit ' '.join(testString.split(' ', 4)[2:4])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 752 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit ' '.join(testString.split(' ')[2:4])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 886 ns per loop
```

Comment: Good point on the timing. Also, note that in real life, he'd probably split the line once (as he does at the very top) and then use the list a bunch of times, in which case the benefit of finding the maximum number of splits across all of his uses would be even smaller, and the cost to simplicity even higher.